# In a ring if a product is invertible with one factor is not a divisor of zero then both factors are invertible

Tags: ring-theory

Let $(A,+,.)$ be a ring, and $a$ et $b$ two elements of $A$ such that $ab$ is invertible and $b$ is not a divisor of zero. I want to show that $a$ and $b$ are invertible.

My try: since $ab$ is invertible there exists $x\in A$ such that $(ab)x=1$ and $x(ab)=1$ by associativity of $"."$, we have that $a(bx)=1$ so to show that $a$ is invertible it remains to show that $(bx)a=1$ but i don't see how to do it. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Start with showing that $b$ is invertible. You know that $b$ is not a zero divisor, that helps showing it.

Comment: b is not a zero divisor means that $\forall\; y\in A-\{0\}$ we have that $by\not = 0$ and $yb\not =0$ but how to exploit this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $xab=1$ you have $bxab=b$, hence $(bxa-1)b=0$ and as $b$ is not a zero divisor $bxa=1$. Since also $abx=1$, we see that $bx$ is a (two-sided) inverse of $a$ and $xa$ is a (two-sided) inverse of $b$.

Answer (score 2):

A key piece of Hagen von Eitzen's argument which is useful elsewhere is the following cancellation law:

#### Lemma

If $p$ is not a zero divisor and $qp=rp$, then $q=r$.

#### Proof

$0=qp-rp=(q-r)p$.